# How to apply scale with image in coreldraw

Tags: corel-draw

I have created a visiting card size design. And now i want to increase its size to 10feet. But the problem is some it has text and object i have given hairline to it. The hairline thickness to every  object its different with different color. When i created the visiting card size design i forgot to check the option **scale with image**. Now i want to enable the option **scale with image** to all the hairlines. Doing manually  will take much time. Any way  to add a check mark to **scale with image** to all the hairlines. I created a macro but it select all the object and text etc and give a hairlines to non hairline object. Any other way  or option to make unable to **scale with image** object so that i can scale my  design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all and check the checkbox.

This does not mean that all objects will now have the same outline thickness, it means that all objects, regardless of the with of the outline will scale, even if they do not have an outline at all.

1. Do not touch the selection box marked in red.
2. Only check the box marked with green.

[image]

Comment: i tried but it create default hairline to non object (which do not have hairline)

Comment: No, it does not.